# Usage of 'to leak'

Tags: word-usage

Do you think the following sentence  is grammatically correct, which is regarding the law of conservation of energy.

> A "closed system" is a bit like a sealed box around whatever we're
>   studying: no energy can leak into the box from the inside (or be
>   introduced to the box from outside).

I assume that the sentence means by:

no energy can leak into the box from the inside: energy going from the box

be introduced to the box from outside: energy coming into the box

So I think it should have been written as:

A "closed system" is a bit like a sealed box around whatever we're studying: no energy can leak into the box from the **outside** (or be introduced to the box from outside).

or

A "closed system" is a bit like a sealed box around whatever we're studying: no energy can leak (into) the **outside** from the **box** (or be introduced to the box from outside).

Comment: Whether "inside" should be used in the original example or not is a logic question, not a language one, though the ( ) statement makes it seem like a typo. In your last example, you can't write "into outside", it would grammatically need to be "into *the* outside" but it does not make logical sense either.

Comment: It looks like a typo, and should probably read: "no energy can leak out from the inside nor leak in from the outside"

Comment: @Peter Thank you .I was looking for an answer like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a typo, and should probably read:

> A "closed system" is a bit like a sealed box around whatever we're studying:
>   no energy can leak **out of** the box from the inside (or be introduced **into** the box from outside).